# ggplot line plot of probability density function is not smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing, probability-density

The mode of this plot is not smooth:

```
library(ggplot2)
my_func<-function(x) {dgamma(x=x, shape=208.419, scale = 31.87409, log = FALSE)}     
a<-ggplot(x<-data.frame(x=c(0,20000)),aes(x=x))
a + stat_function(fun=my_func)
```

What R code would fix this?

Comment: Compute more points with `stat_function(fun=my_func, n=2000)`, as mentioned here: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/stat_function.html

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks very much.